# jQuery/JavaScript Split String by Commas that are Outside of Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using jQuery & JavaScript!!

I have a string, for example

```
"cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1), ease-in, ease-out, linear"
```

..and I want to split it into this array:

```
// (the following has no leading or trailing spaces:)

Array[4]
  0: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)
  1: ease-in
  2: ease-out
  3: linear
```

..but instead I get:

```
Array[7]
  0: cubic-bezier(0.25
  1: 0
  2: 0.25
  3: 1)
  4: ease-in
  5: ease-out
  6: linear
```

I have attempted a dozen solutions, only to find that any way that I try it doesn't work thus far. Here are a few of my previous attempts:

```
var myString = "cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1), ease-in, ease-out, linear";

myString.split(",(?![^\(\)]*>)");

myString.split('(?:\(.*?\))|(,)');

myString.split(",(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))");

myString.split(",(?![^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?\))");

myString.split('/,(?![^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?\)/g');

myString.split(",(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?![^()]*\\))");
```

I am familiar with basic regex rules, such as capture groups and selectors, but am still confused on lookaheads or how I would solve my current situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Match any comma not inside parentheses

```js
var myString = "cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1), ease-in, ease-out, linear";

var parts    = myString.split(/\,\s?(?![^\(]*\))/);

console.log(parts)
```

```
/\,\s?(?![^\(]*\))/
```

- `\,` matches the character `,` literally
- `\s?` matches any whitespace character. The `?` quantifier matches between zero and one times
- `(?![^\(]*\))` Negative Lookahead asserts that the regex does not match a single character not present in the list below
- `[^\(]` Quantifier. Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- `\(` matches the character `(` literally
- `\)`  matches the character `)` literally

Comment: This will also suffice his condition? `\,\s(?!.*\))`

Comment: You sir, adeneo are a genius! I had no idea you could input a regex without surrounding it with quotation marks! Thank you!! Wow, the split parameter is not in quotation marks!!! Thank you!

Comment: Note: This does not account for multiple embedded parentheses. `1,(2,(3,4)),5` will result in `[ "1", "(2", "(3,4))", "5"]`.

Comment: so @user2867288 this is my usecase =D