# RegEx find certain character but not if between certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having kind of a nightmare about this regEx I need to provide. The idea is basically to find all ',' characters between parenthesis within a certain string... but if inside that parenthesis there's another parenthesis that contain ',' then don't include this.

Sample:

```
(hello, something, hi, (another, one), last)
```

So the idea would be to detect and match 5 groups

```
1. (hello,
2. something,
3. hi,
4. (another, one),
5. last)
```

I've been struggling but I can't break it up like this, instead I get 6 groups

```
1. (hello,
2. something,
3. hi,
4. (another,  <-- not ok
5. one), <-- not ok
6. last)
```

Have been trying with some regEx but I can't detect the double ( ) pattern, the best I could achieved so far was

```
(?!\(.*)[,](?=.*\))
```

Thanks for the time and help

Comment: This can't be done with a regex.

Comment: Maybe you can remove the outer parentheses and then use a solution like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071509. However, this sounds as if you need to write some parsing function here.

Comment: Try `([A-Za-z]+|\([^()]+,[^()]+\))`

Comment: How deep can the inner parentheses be nested

Comment: @JGNI only once....

Comment: @ran_0315 actually this detects the inner parenthesis with the comma, which I good I suppose with some extra coding. Will take it into account if this can't be solved with a single regEx. thanks for the tip

Comment: Try `\([^()]*\),?|\S[^,]*,?`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/6jg92v/1

Comment: What I commented above doesn't produce desired output on a subject string that doesn't have a nested pair of parentheses. Please try `(?!^\s*\()\([^()]*\),?|\S[^,\r\n]+,?` instead. See it in action https://regex101.com/r/7mjSKH/1

Comment: There's a bunch of trivial ways to break that example including just changing the word "something" to "a". Agree with the melpomene comment though this doesn't seem like a smart job for regex, you can spend a bunch of time writing quite a complicated regex that will only work under narrow conditions and not in a generalized sense.

Comment: this is not possible just with regex. you may want to read a response I've just posted about this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124287/handling-duplicate-regex-group-name-in-java-c-translation/52800845#52800845

Comment: it boils down to 'regex engine does not keep state. They just shove stuff into buckets.'